# Definição para campo data e hora

Tags: java, jsf

Estou definindo 2 atributos, um será data e o outro hora:

```
@Getter
@Setter
private Date dataOcorrencia;

@Getter
@Setter
private Calendar horaOcorrencia;
```

Gostaria de saber se é a melhor definição para ambos, porque tem ainda a classe `SimpleDataFormat`. Essa é a melhor definição pra ambos?

Comment: Isso depende do que você quer fazer com essas datas. O java 8 lançou uma nova API para datas (java.time) que eu particularmente achei interessante. Com ela você poderia usar LocalDate e LocalTime, com a vantagem de ser thread-safe (java.util.Date não é) e bem mais simples de usar.

Answer (score -1):

Sugiro unificar estes 2 atributos em um campo apenas, utilizando o tipo oriundo do Java 8:

```
@Getter
@Setter
private LocalDateTime dhOcorrencia;
```

Além de vários benefícios, como imutabilidade, interface fluente, fácil manipulação (operações básicas como soma, subtração, cálculo de períodos), tratamento de datas inválidas, terá mais facilidade para ordenação por esta informação.

Alguns exemplos de uso do `LocalDateTime`:

```
LocalDateTime hojeAoMeioDia = LocalDate.now().atTime(12,0);

LocalTime agora = LocalTime.now();
LocalDate hoje = LocalDate.now();
LocalDateTime dataEhora = hoje.atTime(agora);


LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2014, 12, 25, 10, 30);
```